# How to edit / ungroup EMF pastes in PPT using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

it's Martin from Berlin (Germany - so please excuse my wrong English)...

I'm trying to edit EMF pastes in PPT using VBA. The EMF pastes are Excel charts and I used
**ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=3** (enhanced metafile)

Without VBA it is easy: Just rightclick the image and "ungroup" (2x).

In VBA I tried the following:
1. Selecting the right shape (works), then
**ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Ungroup.Select**

This runs on an error: *"...cannot ungroup*".

In another thread a "solution" was given: Recording a macro -> not possible in PPT 2007!
When I record a macro in PPT 2003, it says exactly the same:
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Ungroup.Select
but it doesn't work.

It seems that there should be one step before that converts the emf image into "office format" (if you do it without VBA after clicking "ungroup" a message box occurs that askes, if you want to convert the graphics into "office format").

Any idea what to do that ungroup is working with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

This works here:

```
Sub UngroupPastedChart()
Dim oShRange As ShapeRange
Dim oSh As Shape
Set oShRange = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
Set oShRange = oShRange.Ungroup
Set oShRange = oShRange.Ungroup
End Sub
```

and add oShRange.Select if you want the ungrouped shapes to be selected at the end.